# Javascript syntax : a != b && (c = b)

Tags: javascript, syntax

I'm not really a guru in JavaScript.
I saw this syntax :
`a != b && (c = b);`
Can someone explain this to me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: the most basic tutorial will tell you this... Although, it could be a typoo?

Comment: Sorry but I code a bit and I never saw a logical <code>AND</code> to make a sort of if... If you can link me a tutorial where you find it I would appreciate!

Comment: Look up `Short circuit evaluation`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `a != b`, assign `b` to `c`, returning `c` if `c` is truthy.

Comment: Thanks for your help! (And I also thank the others...)

Answer (score 2):

If `a` is not equal to `b`, then assign `b` to `c`.

Here the right side won't evaluate if the left side is not `true`.

Answer (score 1):

In your example the result would be if `a != b` then assign `b` to `c`.  The evaluation of whether `c` is truthy isn't handled (in this example).

This statement works like a short-hand `if` statement because of operator short-circuiting.

When using a logical AND `&&`, this means if the left hand side of the AND is `false` then the right hand side of the AND won't be evaluated.  So a logical AND can be abused to form a kind of short-hand `if` statement.  This also happens in reverse for logical ORs, if the left hand side evaluates to `true`, then the right hand side won't be evaluated (as it will not alter the overall result).  You'll find this operator short-circuiting quirk in languages like C, JavaScript and Java.

Answer (score 0):

if variable `a` is not equal to variable `b`, assign variable `b` to variable `c`

Answer (score 0):

It should rather be written as:

```
if (a != b) {
  c = b;
}
```

The code uses the short circuit of the `&&` operator for flow control (i.e. the second part of the expression is only evaluated if the first is true), then it uses the fact that an assignment is also an expression to be able to do the assignment in an expression, and ignoring the value of the expression.